# React Native Copying Old State

Tags: react-native

In React Native if I want to copy old state I can use the following code:

```
  this.setState((previousState) => {
        return {
          places : previousState.places.concat(previousState.placeName)
        }
    })
```

But I was wondering if I can use the ReactJS syntax here: This does not seems to work and throws an error.

```
this.setState({
    ...state, 
    places : this.state.places.concat(this.state.placeName) 
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off your example given `state` will be `undefined`. What you want is probably:

```
this.setState({ 
    ...this.state, 
    places: this.state.places.concat(this.state.placeName)
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a preference on which one to use when?

Comment: The short answer is `this.state`. But the real issue is that you were referencing a variable `state` which most likely was not declared (it may have been, but from the example I can't say that). When writing code in a react component you will want to reference any properties on the instance with the `this` keyword (e.g. `this.state`, `this.someOtherProperty`)

Answer (score 1):

have you used ...this.state ? if it is inside a function, then state will return undefined.